# Basic CSS div height doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

So I was making a page, and I created a new div. I set both the height and the width of the div to a 100px each, and put the background blue, just so I can see the div while I position it. As you can see, that's the only code for that div

```css
.portfoliobox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfoliobox">
</div>
```

However, my div looks like

[image]

I tried refreshing, opening a new page, creating a new div, but it doesn't seem to go away like a normal bug should. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Seriously. Be nice.  Include code, not a picture.  Read the "how to ask" section of the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @Colt83.  Sounds like you're frustrated. It would be helpful to see your html markup along with the css file relevant to it.

Comment: The code should work just fine... as mentioned above, add your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Otherwise post the whole html and css code maybe the div is changed by something.

```css
.portfoliobox {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background: blue;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="portfoliobox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.portfoliobox {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfoliobox">
</div>
```

It worked perfect for me. I think that you might had mistyped the value of height. Can you please provide the whole source code.